# How to check if a file is mapped by the other process in C language on linux?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

Sorry I have no idea if the title is the key point of my problem. Here is the thing:

There are some resources that multiple processes share together, so I use mmap to share the information between different process.

To be specific, there is a bitmap in the mapped file. If a process use the a resource, it set the corresponding bit on the bitmap, and clear the bit when don't need it anymore.

But some process may crush or be killed sometimes, and the bit it set on the bitmap won't be clear anymore. It should be cleared when no process is using it. So I try to check if there are other process using the mapped file.

Comment: Look into file locking instead.

Comment: What is the relation of these processes in the process tree? Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that establishes this environment?

Comment: @Oka There is no relation between these processes. Actually, I'm program a dynamic library, so it can be used by any process.

Comment: Your concept has more problems. Two processes could check and set the bit at the same time or overwrite modifications done by other processes beccause setting or clearing a bit might be read-modify-write operations. Even if you can find out which processes have mapped the file you don't know if any of the existing processes has set a specific bit without using other communication between the processes.  This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and describe the original problem you are trying to solve with the shared memory-mapped file.

Comment: @Bodo Your worries are right. Actually, I declare a lock in the mapped file to protect the bitmap. Before process A modifying the bitmap, it will try to get the lock, then other processes can't modifying the bitmap before process A unlock it.

Comment: I solved the problem by "flock" based on Shawn’s advice. Here is the detail:
1. try to get a "exclusive lock" from the based file. If flock return success, clear the bitmap(it means no other process is using the mapped file)

 the Thanks all of you

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by "flock" based on Shawn’s advice(in comment area). Here is the detail:

1. According to the instructions for using flock”, "Shared lock" and "exclusive lock" cannot be obtained at the same time, while "shared lock" can be obtained by multiple processes at the same time.
2. When process A begin to run, try to get a "exclusive lock" from the mapped file. If flock return success, clear the bitmap(it means no other process is using the mapped file).
3. Then process A release the "exclusive lock", and try to get a "shared lock" from the mapped file. According to "1", before process A exit, other processes can only get a "shared lock", and can't get a "exclusive lock". (it means there are some processes using the bitmap, so it shouldn't clear the bitmap).
4. If process A exit, it will release the "shared lock", then other process could get the "exclusive lock", and it can clear the bitmap.

Comment: I suggest to use a synchronization mechanism provided by the OS *instead* of your bitmap, not in addition to it. For example semaphores can be used in a way that the operation will be undone automatically on process exit.